# How do I modify object permissions using aws s3 command?

Tags: amazon-s3

It seems to me that `aws s3` does not have a dedicated command to modify object permissions. I have some files that are uploaded via s3fuse. Afterwards, I would like to make them public. Is there any way to make those files public using `aws s3` command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to do this. It seems there is another cli called `aws s3api`, that mimics the underlying s3 api. Using `aws s3api put-object-acl` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html command, I can change object permissions directly.

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --acl public-read --bucket mybucket --key targets/my_binary
```